# Best way to automatically update HTML DOM (instead reloading page for reading database)

Tags: jquery, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Asp.Net MVC and SQL server. I would like to update the HTML content with new data from database without having to reload the page. What's the best way to do so?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <div class="student">
        <div>           
            <label>
                @item.Name @item.LastName
            </label> 
            <br/>           
            <span>@item.School  @item.Course</span>
            ....
            <br />            
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What's the **best** way...?" I'll give you the best way in my opinion (not necessarily the most easy way but not too hard also)

I recommend to use **ReactJS** for this.
React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.
The main rule of react it's to manage the page's render process in the most efficient way as a response to a user interaction or as a response to new incoming data from the server (usually by **AJAX** requests).

What's **AJAX**?
It's a method of retrieving data from a server without refreshing the page.
AJAAX use the browser's built-in XMLHttpRequest object for making these requests and by using JavaScript it's leads to changes in the HTML DOM (here react fits in) without refreshing the page, **but just re-rendering the necessary parts**.

If you also mean that the page should re-render as a response to changes on the server: when the server need to initiate a request to the client (for example: when the server need to inform the page that a data has changed),
what you need it's a tool to enable you that "push notifications" ability.
I recommend you to try SignalR (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

Comment: Thanks, btw, I'm using two different project in my solution, one for in-data and one for out-data. I'm a bit confused since some post says it's not possible SignalR, and some says it might. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I had used SignalR in my projects with a great success.
You can take a look on a project of mine used MVC and SignalR: 
https://github.com/RoiNeuman/ChatApp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the page content depending on some events, like user clicking a button, typing some text, then what you're looking for is "Ajax". Google it, you will find a lot of information explaining what it is and how to use it.

But if you're building a real time application like real-time messaging apps, you can search for SignalR, it is a library for ASP.NET

Comment: I understand Ajax is a kind of JQuery/JavaScript. But how can it know/feel if there's new data in database? I would like to have an instant update when there's a new row in database.

Comment: @sav you'll still implement the database logic in the controller but you will update the page content using ajax.

Comment: @sav but if you're building a real time application like real-time messaging apps, you can search for SignalR, it is a library for ASP.NET

Comment: @JamesHaug , @Lianthe So I should send message(e.g. `Id`)  when I'm creating a new row to database -> Then, when `message(id)` is received, I'll use Ajax to add the new row into page content. Is the idea correct?

Comment: by sending message, I mean using SignalR

Comment: @sav, Yes, that's one method to do it. Alternatively, you can send the entire contents via SignalR, and the JS can render out and append the HTML. A data-binding library works well with SignalR, such as knockoutjs: http://knockoutjs.com/. This post isn't a half bad example: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2013/01/28/using-knockoutjs-with-signalr-in-asp-net-mvc/